# Text contains search without database

Tags: database, search

I have a 15 million datas. And each datas has name, title.
And all datas just in text file.

How can I find a datas that contains a some text.

Search Text: `hi`
Example Data:

```
peter|Just text.
brown|hi, nice to meet you
john|hello, world!
hi|hello
hello|this is not matched data.
...
```

Result Data:

```
brown|hi, nice to meet you
hi|hello
...
```

When I just searching. It spends 7 seconds.
But, I want to faster like database.
How can I do?

Comment: You can't. It will take some finite time to read every line of that 15M record file, and there is no way to know a line contains [whatever you are looking for this time] without reading every line.

Comment: @TonyAndrews Yes, I know that can't make faster with reading every line. So I want to make something like index.

Comment: @TonyAndrews And the datas will use very many time.

Comment: I know what you want.  My point is, you can't!  Think what such an "index" would need to contain to work - all the text of all the records of your file.  It would be as big as, or bigger than, the file itself!  Of course you could create a sort-of index of all the records that contain 'hi' by greping them into a smaller file, then next time you want to know which records contain 'hi' you look at the smaller file.  But that's not what you mean I imagine!